# Access to this API denied due to authorization error

Tags: python, line-api, line-messenger

I wanted to make my own LINE Bot using LINE Messaging API. I have cloned the [sample echo bot](https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-python/tree/master/examples/flask-echo) using Flask in Python and succesfuly deployed the bot on Heroku. The Heroku Procfile contents are as follows
`web: gunicorn app:app`

I have entered the correct channel secret and channel access token. I expected the bot to echo the messages back to me. Unfortunately, when I tried sending messages to the LINE bot, the bot won't echo the messages sent to it and returned the following error message

```
2023-01-16T14:30:52.927195+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/callback" host=maid-chan.herokuapp.com request_id=502e05cb-10d1-46b5-b451-fd42984520d5 fwd="147.92.149.165" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1068ms status=500 bytes=438 protocol=https
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924657+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-01-16 14:30:52,922] ERROR in app: Exception on /callback [POST]
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924683+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924683+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924683+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924684+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924684+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924684+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924684+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924684+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924685+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924685+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 57, in callback
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924685+00:00 app[web.1]:     handler.handle(body, signature)
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924685+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/linebot/webhook.py", line 259, in handle
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924685+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.__invoke_func(func, event, payload)
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924686+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/linebot/webhook.py", line 271, in __invoke_func
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924686+00:00 app[web.1]:     func(event)
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924686+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 66, in message_text
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924687+00:00 app[web.1]:     line_bot_api.reply_message(
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924687+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/linebot/api.py", line 113, in reply_message
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924687+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._post(
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924687+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/linebot/api.py", line 1860, in _post
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924687+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.__check_error(response)
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924687+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/linebot/api.py", line 1896, in __check_error
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924688+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise LineBotApiError(
2023-01-16T14:30:52.924688+00:00 app[web.1]: linebot.exceptions.LineBotApiError: LineBotApiError: status_code=403, request_id=bd667144-c714-4ef7-a298-b58aca43ee9b, error_response={"details": [], "message": "Access to this API denied due to authorization error"}, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Server': 'envoy', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'x-frame-options': 'DENY', 'x-line-request-id': 'bd667144-c714-4ef7-a298-b58aca43ee9b', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'Content-Length': '66', 'Expires': 'Mon, 16 Jan 2023 14:30:52 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Date': 'Mon, 16 Jan 2023 14:30:52 GMT', 'Connection': 'close'}
2023-01-16T14:30:52.929820+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.54.190 - - [16/Jan/2023:14:30:52 +0000] "POST /callback HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "-" "LineBotWebhook/2.0"
```

Comment: Sample code requires environment variables to exist. Did you forget to set those in Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that it had something to do with the IP address on the security settings. Thank you ksyt for answering my question. Refer to this link for more information
https://www.line-community.me/ja/question/63c5590adb53a1550053aa0d/access-to-this-api-denied-due-to-authorization-error?sortby=votes